# c# : Callbacks on HTTP POST

Tags: c#, http, post, callback

I wonder if you could please help me? Do any of you perhaps know of a way to setup a callback on an HTTP POST? I can get the response from the POST no problem, but it is a requirement on a project that I am working on that I should setup a callback to receive additional data as well.

Here is a snippet of the c# code I have in place:

...

```
httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

//Set HttpWebRequest properties
byte[] bytes;
bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlString);
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

//Get stream object
requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

//Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

//Close stream
requestStream.Close();

//Sends the HttpWebRequest and wait for its response
httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

if (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //Get response stream
    responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

   //Obviously from here we can get the response etc..      
}

//Close HttpWebResponse, 
httpWebResponse.Close();
```

...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by *callback*? Code on your client that is called by the server whenever a POST has occured? If it is just about the additional data, it would be the easiest approach to add these to the response of the POST. Otherwise, you could have a look at https://www.asp.net/signalr.